# UN Global Comtrade Database

Tags: data-request, economics, trade, un

UN Comtrade database, the major source of bilateral trade data online, has a free query tool: 
http://comtrade.un.org/data/

However, the API limits the number of requests per hour and the size of each request.

I was wondering if anyone has the full database saved somewhere to download as a mirror (or someone has a token available to access bulk downloading)? Writing a timed script is rather burdensome, so I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: there is a bulk API --> https://comtrade.un.org/Data/Doc/api/bulk although it's not clear how one gets access, so email --> comtrade@un.org

Comment: Great, thanks I will send them an e-mail. They do have a waiver for certain institutions, as stated on their website: "The 50,000 records per query limitation is waived for the following users: institutional users (Academic institutions, government, inter-government agencies, NGOs) data providers, permanent missions to the United Nations and members of the Committee for the Coordination of Statistical Activities (CCSA).", so I have sent them an e-mail!